# how to open up a child process to tail the files present in a config file using python on a mac machine?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am trying to tail the files in a config file using python on mac

I am able to get the values from the config file but not able to open up child processes for the same

a sample config file has

> [section1]
>
> host_prefix = true
>
> timestamp_prefix = true
>
> [section2]
>
> host = localhost
>
> port = 1463
>
> pids = /var/run/harvester
>
> [files]
>
> apache.access =  /var/log/apache2/access.log
>
> apache.errors = /var/log/apache2/errors.log
>
> mail =  /var/log/mail.log
>
> mysql.log =  /var/log/mysql.log

I am opening up the config file and trying to get the filepaths and I need to tail them in new child processes in separate terminals

```
    #! /bin/env python
import StringIO
import os
import re
from multiprocessing import Process
COMMENT_CHAR = '#'
OPTION_CHAR =  '='

def parse_config(filename):
    options = {}
    f = open(filename)
    for line in f:
        if COMMENT_CHAR in line:
           line, comment = line.split(COMMENT_CHAR, 1)
        if OPTION_CHAR in line:
            option, value = line.split(OPTION_CHAR, 1)
            option = option.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            options[option] = value
    f.close()
    return options

try:
    f = open("/etc/harvest.conf", 'r')
    print 'found'
    options = parse_config('/etc/harvest.conf')
    print options.values()
    os.system('tail -f options.values')
except:
        try: 
            f = open("/usr/local/etc/harvest.conf", 'r')
            print 'found'
            options = parse_config('/usr/local/etc/harvest.conf')
            print options.values()
            os.system('tail -f options.values')
        except IOError:
            print 'cannot find file'
```

the above code gives me all the values from the config file that includes 'localhost','1463'
but I want only the paths from the file and need to tail them in separate child processes

Comment: Do you want to `tail -f` all the four files list in your [files] section? the first `tail -f` will block others until you kill it.

Comment: I want to tail -f each file in a separate terminal window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html). It can work with INI files.

Comment: how do I start a child process for the files in a new terminal

Comment: @Rishabh: Correct, but it in INI file format. My point was that you don't need to implement parser by your self.

Answer (score 1):

1. use [os.path.exists](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to check if a file exists
2. use [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#examples) to parse an ini-type config file